# Groovy SQL eachRow requires ResultSet to be returned

Tags: groovy

Groovy's SQL provides an eachRow() method but it seems to generate an uncatchable error if the SQL statement being executed doesn't produce a ResultSet, e.g. an INSERT statement. Of course Groovy SQL also provides an execute() method for SQL statements that don't produce a ResultSet.  My challenge is that if the SQL statements are provided by users then I'm wondering how to know which method to use?  I was hoping that eachRow() would throw an exception that could be caught/swallowed if there was no ResultSet but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Here's a snippet showing what I tried.  In the example, it reads SQL statements from stdin, and attempts to process them using eachRow().

```
System.in.readLines().each {
    dbsql = it
    try {
        println "processing sql"
        dbconn.eachRow(dbsql) {
            n++
        }
        println "processed result ($n rows)"
    } catch(SQLException ex) {
      rslt = 2
      println ">>> query failed against ${dbhost}/${dbname}:")
      println "  ${ex}"
    } catch(Exception ex) {
      rslt = 255
      println ">>> general failure"
      println "  ${ex}"
    }
```

Instead of either catch block executing, I get error messages that look like,

```
Dec 01, 2023 12:45:13 AM groovy.sql.Sql eachRow
WARNING: Failed to execute:  insert into mytable (name) values ('John Doe'); because: This SQL statement does not return a single ResultSet
>>> query failed against dbhost/wrk:
  java.sql.SQLException: This SQL statement does not return a single ResultSet
```

Hoping someone can help with Groovy SQL usage where the SQL statements are not known ahead of time as in this case where they are coming from a file.

Note: everything works smoothly for SELECT statements (since they return ResultSets).

Comment: check if the statement starts with `insert`, `update` or alike and fire `execute()` in this case

Comment: If you are not inside a TX, I'd handle this exact error in the catch. If there is no utility for that in Groovy/JDBC, I doubt there is a simple solution to this problem, because you can write any sort of statements depending on the underlying database.

Comment: here is an example with raw java. should work in groovy as well: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-multiple-result-sets?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for single resultset or rowcount the groovy code could be like this:

```
@Grab(group='com.microsoft.sqlserver', module='mssql-jdbc', version='12.4.2.jre8')
@GrabConfig(systemClassLoader=true)

import groovy.sql.Sql

Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")
def connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://...:1433;databaseName=...;user=...;password=...";  

def rsWorker = {hasResult, rs->
    if(hasResult){
        println "resultset:"
        rs.each{ println "  row: ${it}" }
    }else{
        println "update count: ${rs}"
    }
}

Sql.withInstance(connectionUrl){dbconn->
    dbconn.execute("select getdate() as today, 'hello' as world", rsWorker)
    dbconn.execute("create table #tmp(i int)", rsWorker)
    dbconn.execute("select getdate() as today, 'goodby' as world", rsWorker)
    dbconn.execute("update deleteme set iAnnualSum=0", rsWorker)
}
```

output example:

```
resultset:
  row: [today:2023-12-01 15:14:54.303, world:hello]
update count: 0
resultset:
  row: [today:2023-12-01 15:14:54.363, world:goodby]
update count: 28
```

databases like microsoft sql server supporting multiple resultsets and i don't see how to process them in groovy.

however here is a good java example that could be easily ported to groovy: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-multiple-result-sets?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks, this is pretty much exactly what I wanted.  I understand about the complexities of multi-resultset databases like SQLServer but I was just after the single resultset situation which your answer solved superbly.  Completed all my testing and everything is working smoothly - thanks again.  

Now I just wonder where to find more documentation, etc., on those closures...  :)  

Like how did you know that the closure would have have that "hasResult" value passed in?

Comment: i knew that in plain jdbc the Statement.execute returns `true/false` for `result/count`. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#execute-java.lang.String- so, i was looking in groovy Sql doc for execute method and there is a description in corresponding method with example:  https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html#execute(java.lang.String,groovy.lang.Closure)  PS: the official example is ugly ;-)

Comment: Thanks @daggett!  I don't suppose you know how I can call a method from inside that closure...  I'm hoping to call a method (that I would write) to process the result instead of "rs.each{ println "  row: ${it}" }".

Comment: normally you should be able to call any methods from closure.
maybe it would be simpler for you to declare `rsWorker` as a method: `def rsWorker(hasResult, rs){...}`, then you can use it as a closure: `dbconn.execute("...", &rsWorker)`. and from this method you can call other methods... but if you have an issue - better to ask another question